# VS Code extension how to detect if sidebar or terminal clicked?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am trying to detect if the user clicks on the sidebar or the panel in a VS code window in order to develop an extension. Is there a way in VS code to detect where the user has last clicked/what is active at a moment?